# Why am I receiving the "Invoke-RestMethod : Not Found" error?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I am trying to invoke a powershell script that uses the Invoke_RestMethod call. The powershell script works as is on a colleague's computer but not on my computer which is exactly the same. I'm receiving the following error

```
15:47:48.270 Invoke-RestMethod : Not Found
15:47:48.271 At C:\Program Files (x86)\TRICENTIS\Tosca Testsuite\ToscaCI\Client\deliver.ps1:15 char:1
15:47:48.272 + Invoke-RestMethod -Body $body -Method 'Post' -Uri $url
```

This is the powershell script that I'm calling called delver.ps1

```bsh
$url = 'https://pulse-us-east-1.qtestnet.com/webhook/b9303bb6-d0e1-43ce-bf96be4a3b330c8f'

Set-Location -Path "C:\Tosca_Projects\Tosca_Workspaces\First Steps\Test Results"

$payload = (Get-Content "result.xml" -Raw)

$body = @{
'projectId' = '95814'
'test-cycle' = '3539385'
'requiresDecode' = 'true'
'result' = $payload
}

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-RestMethod -Body $body -Method 'Post' -Uri $url
```

I'm running Windows 10 Powershell Version 5.1.17763.503 and I've even upgraded to powershell 6.2.3 and I get the same error

Comment: Have you tried this using `https://postman-echo.com/post` just to verify that it works with a URL that does return a response?   I'm suspecting that "Not Found" is the message being returned with a 404 response.

Comment: Glenn, That worked, very interesting...

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this error multiple times in the last days, and even tough is cryptic in the sense that you might think it's because the cmdlet is not fun, in reality is because the URL is not found, basically a 404 error code internally.

Try to test de URL step by step and be very careful at the quotation marks ( where they stand and end ) + possible chars that need to be escaped.
https://pulse-us-east-1.qtestnet.com/

Good luck, it's just about paying extra attention